# Do badges give reputation?

Tags: discussion

Does earning some badge increase one's reputation. Earlier I assumed it did not, but then on the badges page it says things like 'x awarded' with varying value of x for each badge , what does it mean ?

Comment: That's the number of times the badge has been awarded (i.e. the number of users, for those you can only get once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, badges do not give you any reputation. The 'x awarded' number tells you how many times that badge is awarded.